# Why does Switch wear white in The Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

All members of Morpheus' team wear black leather and the only one who does not is Switch, also she doesn't wear leather either.

Is it a sign? or not?

Comment: You're looking for an out-of-universe meaning, correct?  Symbology of the filmmaking?  Or an in-universe explanation for her different fashion tastes?

Comment: Or not. Let's leave it at that.

Comment: Follow the white rabbit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made myself this question after I saw the trilogy but I never found any hard interpretation, so I looked up other websites in order to pursuit a "sign" but I didn't find anything. A first note you need to consider is that she wore black in her first scene. As "switcher", she accomplishes with the hacker name because she is the opposite to the team; everyone has dark hair, she has blond, everyone wears dark colors, she wears lighter colors.

One could argue also the **"white interpretation"**: for example, *(letting aside one second to Switch)*, when Neo started his training, Morpheus uploaded the software in Neo's mind, where everything was empty with a white screen, representing the numberless opportunities that he has to do things.

Beyond that, you could make fashion's interpretation. The only thing that come to my mind is Trinity, the other woman in the group. In order to make a difference between both, she wears white.

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess, but I think it's a good one...

Switch was originally intended to be different genders in and out of the Matrix (hence the name Switch). It's possible that the white outfit was designed to highlight that her RSI was different than the others, as well as subconsciously project the duality of her/his nature with the black/white symbolism.

Comment: I read this in a magazine.

Comment: @DSaad - Which magazine and what did it say? I've been trying to track down the quote about Switch being intended to be different genders for years and I've never found the original source...